# compare one column value to another column in single select query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Dear Programmers,
                  I need to compare one column value to another column in single select query.

As my query goes like this:

```
    SELECT ATTNLOG.emp_id,
           ATTNLOG.tdate,
           ATTNLOG.tdate_out,
          (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                               FROM tbl_emp_overtime 
                              WHERE emp_id=ATTNLOG.emp_id 
                                AND ot_indate=ATTNLOG.tdate)
               THEN 0 
               ELSE 1 
          END) as 'STATUS'
    FROM tbl_emp_attn_log ATTNLOG 
   WHERE ATTNLOG.emp_id=201
```

In my case condition i need to compare the every row of ATTNLOG and gives STATUS respectively.

Actually the result returns row values like

```
EMP_ID  TDATE     TDATE_OUT  STATUS
201    2012-2-26  2012-2-26   0
201    2012-2-27  2012-2-27   1
```

and the table tbl_emp_overtime has value like

```
emp_ID  ot_indate
201    2012-2-27
```

But my code gives like

```
EMP_ID  TDATE     TDATE_OUT  STATUS
201    2012-2-26  2012-2-26   1
201    2012-2-27  2012-2-27   1
```

But it don't give the result like that. Please help me out.

Comment: what about just making a left outer join and check for null values? would that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use sql 2008 cast the dates to `date` data type, if the original data type is `datetime` it should help:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_emp_overtime 
WHERE emp_id=ATTNLOG.emp_id 
AND CAST(ot_indate as DATE)=CAST(ATTNLOG.tdate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

try with COUNT(*):

```
SELECT ATTNLOG.emp_id,
           ATTNLOG.tdate,
           ATTNLOG.tdate_out,
          (CASE WHEN  (SELECT count(*)
                               FROM tbl_emp_overtime 
                              WHERE emp_id=ATTNLOG.emp_id 
                                AND trunc(ot_indate)=(ATTNLOG.tdate)) > 0 THEN 0 
               ELSE 1 
          END) as 'STATUS'
    FROM tbl_emp_attn_log ATTNLOG 
   WHERE ATTNLOG.emp_id=201
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it gives the same result as of mine.

Comment: it might be when the dates are compared. can you trunc the dates ? in Oracle its called the TRUNC() function , or try to compare char date mask with char date mask ie in oracle to_char(date,'dd-mon-yyyy') = to_char(date,'dd-mon-yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

try `GREATEST` or `LEAST` as your requitement